# How to crop an image around face with ImageResizer .net?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image-resizing, imageresizer

I have a .net project and I've installed ImageResizer and it works fine when I just give it a size and mode = crop like this:

### The original Image

[image: The Original image]

### Croped

[image: Croped image]

### Code

```
<img src="woman-hat.jpg?width=400&height=400&mode=crop"  />
```

As you see the cropped version is not a nice picture since it is not based on the woman's face. I tried to do that but the documentation is not clear. [Crop around Plugin](https://imageresizing.net/docs/v4/plugins/croparound) and [Faces Plugin](https://imageresizing.net/docs/v4/plugins/faces).

I know that I have to buy a licence for these plugins and of course it is OK if I need to write some code.

### What do I expect

[image: Expected result]

It would be nice if I can do it with a code like this

```
<img src="woman-hat.jpg?width=400&height=400&mode=crop&croparound=face"  />
```

Comment: Have you looked at the [Microsoft Face API](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/face-api)? You can do 30K requests per month for free.

Comment: Have you used c.zoom?

Answer (score 1):

You use `c.focus=faces` to give croparound the coordinates, and `c.zoom=true` to crop as closely as possible to them, rather than minimally.

Example: [image]